# Lowest Common Ancestor in a Binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Following is my implementation of lowest common ancestor for a Binary Search tree. I have two question:

1) The time complexity is O(n) and space complexity is O(n) worse case but O(logn) average case for both time and space if BST is balanced. is that correct?
2) How can i extend my solution to binary trees and not just binary search trees.

Hope to hear from you soon.

```
//The function findOrQueue is to enqueue all elements upto target node to a queue
public void findOrQueue(Node target, Node top, LLQueue q) {
    int cmp = target.getData().compareTo(top.getData()); 
    if(cmp == 0) {
        q.enqueue(top);
        return ;
    }
    else if (cmp < 0) {
        q.enqueue(top);
        findOrQueue(target, top.getLeftChild(),q);
    }
    else {
        q.enqueue(top);
        findOrQueue(target, top.getRightChild(),q);
   }
}

public Node LCA(Node n1, Node n2) throws QueueEmptyException {
    LLQueue q1 = new LLQueue();
    LLQueue q2 = new LLQueue();
    findOrQueue(n1,getRoot(),q1);
    findOrQueue(n2,getRoot(),q2);
    Node t = null;
    while (!q1.isEmpty() && !q2.isEmpty()) {
        Node t1 = (Node)q1.dequeue();
        Node t2 = (Node)q2.dequeue();
        if(t1.getData() != t2.getData()) {
            return t;
        }
        else t = t1;
    }
    if(q1.isEmpty() && q2.isEmpty()) 
        return null;
    else
        return t;
    }
```

Comment: Why wouldn't this work on a plain binary tree? I don't see any condition for this algorithm that mandates a specific node order.

Comment: the function findOrQueue is defined for a binary search tree and not a binary tree

Comment: Why are you using comparisons in `findOrQueue()`? A simple traversal up the tree should suffice.

Comment: i do not have a parent pointer so i have to first find the node.

Answer (score 0):

The key to extending your solution to a general binary tree seems to lie in finding the path connecting the root and a target node. Once obtaining this path, you could easily modify your LCA function to find the lowest common ancestor.

The following crude implementation makes use of `LinkedBlockingQueue` in package *java.util.concurrent*.* and *Stack* in *java.util*.* - however, any other ordinary queue and stack would also do the trick. The code assumes that the target nodes exists in the tree.

```
public static void findPath2(Node target,Node top, Stack<Node> path){
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Node> q1 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Node>(), q2 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Node>(),
    q3 = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Node>();
    Node n = top;
    Node parrent = null;
    while(n.getData().compareTo(target.getData())!= 0){
        parrent = n;
        if(n.right != null){
            q2.add(n.right);
            q3.add(parrent);
        }
        if(n.left != null){
            q2.add(n.left); 
            q3.add(parrent);
        }
        n = q2.remove();
        q1.add(n);
    }

    Stack<Node> s3 = new Stack<Node>(), s2 = new Stack<Node>();
    while(!q3.isEmpty()){
        s3.push(q3.remove());           
    }       
    for(int i = 1; i <= q2.size(); i++)
        s3.pop();       
    while(!s3.isEmpty())
        s2.push(s3.pop());
    while(!q1.isEmpty())
        s3.push(q1.remove());
    LinkedBlockingQueue<Node> temp = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Node>();
    while(!s2.isEmpty())
        temp.add(s2.pop());
    while(!temp.isEmpty())
        s2.push(temp.remove());
    path.push(s3.pop());
    path.push(s2.pop());
    while(!s3.isEmpty()){
        n = s3.peek();          
        while(n.getData().compareTo(path.peek().getData()) != 0 && !s3.isEmpty()){
            s3.pop();
            s2.pop();
            if(!s3.isEmpty())
                n = s3.peek();
        }
        if(!s3.isEmpty()){
            s3.pop();
            path.push(s2.pop());
        }
    }       
}
```